# Sort points in counter-clockwise in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, canvas

I have a set of points introduced into a canvas:
[My canvas with set of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dKtD.png)

I have to apply this algorithm on:
[Algo NoObtuse and example of graph produced by this algo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fayn.png)

My problem is to find, starting from the rightmost point, the following point in the counter-clockwise order (point 2 in algo).

How, then, can we find the following point in this direction each time starting from a point?

**EDIT:** -> Result of the code by ***Blindman67***

```
//First points (before sort and anti-clockwise)
//(6) [Point, Point, Point, Point, Point, Point]
0: Point {x: 458, y: 249, col: "red"}
1: Point {x: 333, y: 40, col: "red"}
2: Point {x: 138, y: 111, col: "red"}
3: Point {x: 336, y: 209, col: "red"}
4: Point {x: 237, y: 251, col: "red"}
5: Point {x: 60, y: 351, col: "red"}

//Points after sort and anti-clockwise
//(6) [Point, Point, Point, Point, Point, Point]
0: Point {x: 336, y: 209, col: "red", angle: 6.456745983859364}
1: Point {x: 333, y: 40, col: "red", angle: 5.156558533568968}
2: Point {x: 138, y: 111, col: "red", angle: 3.75120843247896}
3: Point {x: 60, y: 351, col: "red", angle: 2.4782921522301162}
4: Point {x: 237, y: 251, col: "red", angle: 1.9481922940313214}
5: Point {x: 458, y: 249, col: "red", angle: 0.26263427391514854}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Sorting points in rotational order

To sort points in some direction starting at the right most and using the spatial center as a reference point.

```
// Array of points;
const points = [{x:?,y:?},{x:?,y:?},{x:?,y:?},...?];

// Find min max to get center
// Sort from top to bottom
points.sort((a,b)=>a.y - b.y);

// Get center y
const cy = (points[0].y + points[points.length -1].y) / 2;

// Sort from right to left
points.sort((a,b)=>b.x - a.x);

// Get center x
const cx = (points[0].x + points[points.length -1].x) / 2;

// Center point
const center = {x:cx,y:cy};

// Pre calculate the angles as it will be slow in the sort
// As the points are sorted from right to left the first point
// is the rightmost

// Starting angle used to reference other angles
var startAng;
points.forEach(point => {
    var ang = Math.atan2(point.y - center.y,point.x - center.x);
    if(!startAng){ startAng = ang }
    else {
         if(ang < startAng){  // ensure that all points are clockwise of the start point
             ang += Math.PI * 2;
         }
    }
    point.angle = ang; // add the angle to the point
 });


 // Sort clockwise;
 points.sort((a,b)=> a.angle - b.angle);
```

#### UPDATE correction

```
 // ****************************************************
 // UPDATE the following code is incorrect
 // ****************************************************
 // Sort anti clockwise;
 // points.sort((a,b)=> b.angle - a.angle);
 // ****************************************************

 //=====================================================
 // the correct way to sort anticlockwise     
 //=====================================================

 // first sort clockwise
 points.sort((a,b)=> a.angle - b.angle);

 // then reverse the order
 const ccwPoints = points.reverse();

 // move the last point back to the start
 ccwPoints.unshift(ccwPoints.pop());
```

### Example

Click canvas to rerun on a new set of random points sorted in counter clockwise order.

```js
//.......................................................
// support code not part of the answer
const doFor = (count, cb) => { var i = 0; while (i < count && cb(i++) !== true); }; // the ; after while loop is important don't remove
const setOf = (count, cb = (i)=>i) => {var a = [],i = 0; while (i < count) { a.push(cb(i ++)) } return a };
const eachOf = (array, cb) => { var i = 0; const len = array.length; while (i < len && cb(array[i], i++, len) !== true ); };

const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
const rand  = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
//.......................................................


// set up canvas and context
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 250;
ctx.font = "12px airal";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";


// create random points and then sort them in counterclockwise order 
// starting at the right most 
function doIt() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    function drawPoints() {
        eachOf(points, (point, i) => {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineTo(center.x, center.y);
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle = "white"
            ctx.fillText(i, point.x-2, point.y);
            ctx.fillText(i, point.x+2, point.y);
            ctx.fillText(i, point.x, point.y-2);
            ctx.fillText(i, point.x, point.y+2);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black"
            ctx.fillText(i, point.x, point.y);
        })
    }

    // Array of points;
    var points = setOf(8, () => ({
        x : rand(20, canvas.width - 40),
        y : rand(20, canvas.height - 40),
        angle : 0
    }));

    // Find min max to get center
    // Sort from top to bottom
    points.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y);

    // Get center y
    const cy = (points[0].y + points[points.length - 1].y) / 2;

    // Sort from right to left
    points.sort((a, b) => b.x - a.x);

    // Get center x
    const cx = (points[0].x + points[points.length - 1].x) / 2;

    // Center point
    var center = {
        x : cx,
        y : cy
    };
    // Pre calculate the angles as it will be slow in the sort
    // As the points are sorted from right to left the first point
    // is the rightmost

    // Starting angle used to reference other angles
    var startAng;
    points.forEach(point => {
        var ang = Math.atan2(point.y - center.y, point.x - center.x);
        if (!startAng) {
            startAng = ang
        } else {
            if (ang < startAng) { // ensure that all points are clockwise of the start point
                ang += Math.PI * 2;
            }
        }
        point.angle = ang; // add the angle to the point
    });

    // first sort clockwise
    points.sort((a, b) => a.angle - b.angle);

    // then reverse the order
    const ccwPoints = points.reverse();

    // move the last point back to the start
    ccwPoints.unshift(ccwPoints.pop());
    drawPoints();
}
doIt()
canvas.onclick = doIt;
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. But I tried the code you sent me and I edited the post to show you the result. 

The first element is not the right one after sorting in anti-clockwise and I get the impression that the points are not well classified in the anti-clockwise order (see results ). What do you think?

Comment: @AladinFlex-Tox My bad to fix just sort in clockwise order then reverse the array, last you just move the last point back to the front of the array. See update in answer for how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is a good help. I just saw that for the algorithm NoObtuse I don't need to classify all the points in counterclockwise but I need to find from a point the next point in clockwise or counterclockwise with the parameter FLAG. Do you know how can I do it or maybe I will do another post because you're a very helpful for my student project.

Comment: why add double of PI to an angle?

Comment: @ChanwooPark so that the array of angles are sorted correctly. 2 * PI is 360 degs.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It should be pointed out that the nomenclature of the question / solution can be misleading here. 'Clockwise' typically refers to the direction which the hands move on a clock, where 'counter-clockwise' refers to the opposite direction. The first solution provided (clockwise) sorts the points according to increasing angle, which in relation to the 'right-handed coordinate system' typically used in math and physics is 'counter-clockwise'. It's not a big issue, but can cause confusion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwise#Mathematics